# TestFlight limit each release to specific users

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight

I have done some research and found nothing relevant. I have many iTunes Connected Users who can view and test the builds I release to TestFlight. However, I was wondering if I can target just specific users in each build. For example, I want to upload a build that only the Admin can see. Would that be possible?
Sorry if the question is rather silly, and thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28971591/test-flight-groups-how-to-send-a-build-to-a-group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a group, if you want to make the TestFlight for a specific users, and add their emails to the group. Make sure the group is selected in the left sidebar, by default it will show the list of users you just added.